# Как правильно называется поезд метро?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, люди добрые, как правильно назвать поезд метро? Поезд? Электричка? Метрополитен?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Обычно говорится: в ожидании ПОЕЗДА отойдите от края платформы. Вот еще цитата: "Именные поезда Московского метрополитена — составы, имеющие собственные имена, присвоенные в честь каких-либо людей, событий, в рамках тематических акций и т. п. Как правило, такие СОСТАВЫ имеют какие-либо отличительные особенности".

Comment: Состав - да. Но поезд - тоже да.

Comment: Грузовые..... составы, пассажирские ... поезда

Answer (score 0):

Поезд метро "правильно" называется составом. Как и все поезда на языке железнодорожников (кроме, кажется, электричек - но не уверен).  Можно - метросоставом.
Но ничто не препятствует использовать на бытовом уровне поезд или метропоезд.